# How to assign keys and values dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I want to collect user input details as key value pair.Suppose,in my view side two input fields and added as key value pair in the object.Using `onclick` events more set of input fields are generated dynamically.So then the key value pair added dynamically in the object

I try to implement it in angular2 using input event but no success.

```
currencyObj: any = {
partnerId: '',
currency: '',
val: '',`enter code here`
interactionId: '',
details: {}  
};
```

in template:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="group">
         <button id="buttonlogintoregister" class="small pull-right" type='button' (click)="counterAdd()">Add Fields <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  <hr>
  <div *ngFor='let count of counter'>
 <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="group">
        <input class="inputMaterial" type="text"  [(ngModel)]="currencyObj.details[input1]" required>
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Field1<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="group">
        <input class="inputMaterial" type="text" [(ngModel)]="currencyObj.details[input1]=input2" required>
        <span class="highlight"></span>
        <span class="bar"></span>
        <label>Field2<span style="color:red;"> *</span></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Objects are key value pairs... I don't get what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign keys and values dynamically like this:

```
var k = 'key';
currencyObj[k] = 'value';
```